# $x^x=(1-x)^{(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus

I have this equation $x^x=(1-x)^{(1-x)}$ and I want to find $x$. The solution $x=1/2$ is clear and from the function plots ploted with, for example, [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex%3D(1-x)%5E(1-x)&wal=header), is obvious this is the only situation. But how can I prove that this is the only one? I tried logarithmizing the equation and ariving at $x \ln x =(1-x) \ln(1-x)$, but I still couldn't prove it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Typically 0^0 is defined to equal 1. So x = 0 and x = 1 are also solutions.

Comment: Isn't 0^0 undefined?

Comment: @PeterKagey 0^0 is not defined. You can eventually find its limit, but it's not defined in the usual sense.

Comment: Concrete Mathematics p.162 (R. Graham, D. Knuth, O. Patashnik): Some textbooks leave the quantity 0^0 undefined, because the functions 0^x and x^0 have different limiting values when x decreases to 0. But this is a mistake. We must define x^0=1 for all x , if the binomial theorem is to be valid when x=0 , y=0 , and/or x=-y . The theorem is too important to be arbitrarily restricted! By contrast, the function 0^x is quite unimportant.

Comment: Peter's point (if $0^0=1$, then $x=0$ and $x=1$ are solutions to the equation) is correct. But I wouldn't describe *Concrete Mathematics* as a “typical” source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $\;0<x<1\;$, of course:

$$x^x=(1-x)^{1-x}\iff e^{x\log x}=e^{(1-x)\log(1-x)}\iff x\log x=(1-x)\log(1-x)\iff$$

$$x\left[\log x+\log(1-x)\right]-\log(1-x)=0\;\;\;\color{red}{(**)}$$

Now, we check the function

$$f(x)=x\left[\log x+\log(1-x)\right]-\log(1-x)\implies f'(x)=\log\left(x(1-x)\right)+2$$

Observe that $\;\;0<x<1\implies 0<x(1-x)\le\cfrac12$, and from here, using monotony of the logarithm, we get:

$$f'(x)\le \log\frac12+2=-\log2+2>0$$

so $\;f\;$ is monotone ascending and thus injective, so $\;x=\frac12\;$ is the only solution to $\;\color{red}{(**)}\;$

Answer (score 2):

Put $t=\frac 12 -x$

the equation becomes

$$(\frac 12 -t)^{\frac 12-t}=(\frac12+t)^{\frac 12+t}$$

$\iff$

$$(\frac{1-2t}{1+2t})^{\frac 12-t}=(\frac{1+2t}{2})^{2t}=(\frac{1+2t}{1-2t})^{t-\frac 12}$$

$\implies$

$t=0, $ or $t=\frac 12$ or $t=-\frac 12$

$\implies$

> $x=\frac 12$  or  $x=0$ or $x=1$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how did you obtain the second egality? Because I am obtaining ${{((1-2t)}/{(1+2t))}}^{1/2} = {{(1+2t)}^t} / {2^t} * {{(1-2t)}^t} / {2^t}$

Comment: @JaneDoe i just used $A^n=(\frac{1}{A})^{-n}$.

Comment: Yes, I also used that and I obtain the above equation.

Comment: @JaneDoe Yes you are right. i made some correction. is it ok now.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $f(x)=x^x$ has one local extremum in $(0,1)$ which is the local minimum $(\frac1e,\frac{1}{\sqrt[e]{e}}).$

Assume that $a\in [0,1]$ is a solution of the equation $a^a=(1-a)^{1-a}$. Then $(a-a^2)^a=1-a$ and hence $(a-a^2)^{a^2}=(1-a)^a.$ Dividing the former by the latter, we get
$$(a-a^2)^{a-a^2}=(1-a)^{1-a}=a^a.$$
Since we have one local extremum in the open interval, we deduce that either $a-a^2=1-a\implies a=1$ or $a-a^2=a\implies a=0$ or $a=1-a\implies a=\frac12$.